# VB.NET Timer stops working after it ticks the first time

Tags: vb.net, timer

the timer in my code stops working after the first tick, I have it set to start ticking every second when the form loads:

```
Private Sub FormIdleTimeWaster_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        timerCPS.Interval = 1000
        timerCPS.Start()
End Sub
```

but after the first tick, it stops working:

```
Private Sub TimerCPS_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerCPS.Tick
        lblCPS.Text = CStr(CPS)
        lblTotalHW.Text = CStr(CPS + HWTotal)
    End Sub
```

All the other code refrencing `timerCPS` is

```
Me.timerCPS = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer(Me.components)
```

```
Friend WithEvents timerCPS As Timer
```

Nowhere else references `timerCPS` in my code and I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229328/discussion-on-question-by-crazycraft316-vb-net-timer-stops-working-after-it-tick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replicated your code as given in the question and it is working perfectly fine. It is ticking over every second.

I have modified your code to this:

```
Public Class FormIdleTimeWaster

    Private CPS As Integer = 1

    Private Sub timerCPS_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerCPS.Tick
        CPS += 1
        lblCPS.Text = CStr(CPS)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormIdleTimeWaster_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        timerCPS.Interval = 1000
        timerCPS.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I can clearly see the value in the label increasing by one each tick.

The call to `timerCPS.Start()` is not needed in `timerCPS_Tick`.

If you still have an issue then there is some other code you haven't shown.

Comment: i just somehow forgot to add breakpoints when i was double checking everything before i published the question, sorry for wasting your time and thanks for the all the help and knowledge

Comment: @CrazyCraft316 - No-one has wasted their time so long as you've learnt something and that this question is now here to help future readers.

Comment: Well I hope this helps someone in the future then :)

it just annoys me as a perfectionist that I forgot something so simple